# Java SpringBoot defining multiple datasources error

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I am using springBoot, and am following [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases) tutorial while trying to set up two datasources (pims & powwow).

**application.properties**

```
# pims datasource
spring.datasource1.jdbc-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pims
spring.datasource1.username=postgres
spring.datasource1.password=postgres
# powwow datasource
spring.datasource2.jdbc-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/powwow
spring.datasource2.username=postgres
spring.datasource2.password=postgres
```

**PersistencePimsAutoConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"com.clubtravel.powwow.dao.pims", "com.clubtravel.powwow.repositories.pims"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "pimsEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "pimsTransactionManager")
public class PersistencePimsAutoConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource1")
    public DataSource pimsDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean pimsEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(pimsDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.clubtravel.powwow.entities.pims" });
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager pimsTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(pimsEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

**PersistencePowwowAutoConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"com.clubtravel.powwow.dao.powwow", "com.clubtravel.powwow.repositories.powwow"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "powwowEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "powwowTransactionManager")
public class PersistencePowwowAutoConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource2")
    public DataSource powwowDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean powwowEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(powwowDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.clubtravel.powwow.entities.powwow" });
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager powwowTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(powwowEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

**LobDao.java**

```
@Component
public class LobDao {

    @Autowired
    LobRepository lobRepository;

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<LobEntity> findAll() {
        return lobRepository.findAll();
    }
```

**LobRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface LobRepository extends JpaRepository<LobEntity,Integer> {
}
```

When i start the server, I get the folowing:

**Error**

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field lobRepository in com.clubtravel.powwow.dao.pims.LobDao required a bean of type 'com.clubtravel.powwow.repositories.pims.LobRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.clubtravel.powwow.repositories.pims.LobRepository' in your configuration.
```

I have partitioned the entities, daos and repositories for each separate database.

**More info:**

If I add the repository package:

```
    basePackages = {"com.clubtravel.powwow.dao.pims", "com.clubtravel.powwow.repositories.pims"},
```

The error becomes:

```
Description:

Field lobRepository in com.clubtravel.powwow.dao.pims.LobDao required a bean named 'pimsEntityManager' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'pimsEntityManager' in your configuration.
```

**More info:**

I have also tried adding '@Transactional' to the DAO, but it makes no  difference:

```
@Transactional("pimsTransactionManager")
public List<LobEntity> findAll() {
    return lobRepository.findAll();
}
```

Comment: you defined both data Source's names as pims.

Comment: Hi Issa, thank  you.  I assumed that because I will  still create that database, I can just use the one for now and change it  when  I create it.  I will create the new database now then, and see if the error goes  away.

Comment: I created the new database (update above), but  I still get the same error.

Comment: Hi Richard, hope you doing well. yeah, although I think that the error is not exactly about that, but please let us know about the result and log when you changed the code.

Comment: could you please share repository?

Comment: I have added the DAO and repository now

Answer (score 0):

I had such problem, and it resolved by just adding these annotationsannotations in the main springBoot application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.clubtravel.powwow")
@EntityScan("com.clubtravel.powwow")
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: @Richard please let me know it it works for you?

Comment: thank you for the help, but adding `@EntityScan("com.clubtravel.powwow")` to the springboot app class does not fix it, I still get the same error.

Comment: In my DAO, I have `EntityManager entityManager;`. I am not sure if this should be something else? e.g. `pimsEntityManager`.  But I am not sure how to set that, because the `pimsEntityManager` is defined in the configuration,  and I would think that the config would inject the 'pimsEntityManager'.